# Showing the data with date information as the previous day before a certain time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, date-arithmetic

I have a dataset with date information in MsSQL. The type of this data is registered as datetime. For example I have a date value like '2022-12-12 06:59:00'. Here, if the time is before 07 am, I want it to write '2022/12/11' as the date. If the date value '2022-12-12 07:01:00' is after 07 am I want it to print '2022/12/11' as the date. To be more descriptive, I would like to explain as follows:

| Source | Message | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alarm | Message | 2022-12-12 06:59:00.00000 |
| Alarm2 | Message2 | 2022-12-12 07:01:00.00000 |

This is the current table

I am trying to create the following table:

| Source | Message | TimeStamp | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alarm | Message | 2022-12-12 06:59:00.00000 | 2022/12/11 |
| Alarm2 | Message2 | 2022-12-12 07:01:00.00000 | 2022/12/12 |

How can I do this in SQL query?

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. How they're displayed is up to the client application. If you want just the date part of a `datetime` or `datetime2` value, cast it to a `date`, eg `cast(TimeStamp as date)`

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TimeStamp, 111) AS DATE. I actually convert it to format like this. But before 07 am, I could not make timestamp show the previous day's date and then write today's date. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Dates have no format. What you did is actually a bug - it converted the date to a string with a hard-coded *custom* format. That custom format can't be converted back to a date automatically, so no date function could use it. If you had a date you could subtract 1 day with `DATEADD(d, -1,thatDate)`. This work with all date types and through implicit conversions with recognizable date strings/

Comment: You've written "in MySql", but tagged the question [`tsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [`sql-server`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info). Are you really running a query in SQL Server that retrieves data from a MySQL database?

Comment: I spelled it wrong, why would I do something like that? @HABO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract 7 hours from `TimeStamp` and get the date part only from the result:

```
SELECT *,
       CONVERT(date, DATEADD(HOUR, -7, [TimeStamp])) AS [Date]
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XkZw8orK).

Comment: I really can't thank you enough. Just as I was trying other functions, your answer was exactly what I wanted. I wish everyone could help each other like you. Thank you very much for your help